# QVideoWidget video preview

Tags: c++, qt, video

I'm a beginner! I want to realize a simple video player with Qt Creator on Windows 7 64bit, so I follow the [Video Widget Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/multimediawidgets-videowidget.html). Everything is working fine, but I notice that when I load the video nothing will appear until I press the play button. Is there a way to display the video first frame as a preview? 
I obtain something very similar with start and immediately stop the video, but I suppose this is not the right way to do it.

Comment: You could try using [`QMediaPlayer::setPosition()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qmediaplayer.html#position-prop).

Comment: I tried setPosition() but it doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're doing it the only way it can be currently done. I couldn't find any straightforward APIs that could be used to do it otherwise.

Comment: Maybe I can get the first frame as an image, place it over the video and when I press play remove the image... but I suppose this is a very odd way to do that.

Comment: I also notice that with the play-stop trick the preview disappear if the window lose focus!

Comment: Any news ? Having this issue on QT5.11. After setPosition the video widget is not repaint

Answer (score 0):

It could also be, that the codec, which is neccesary is not present in your system.
I recommenden you to try this project [QtAV](https://github.com/wang-bin/QtAV) which use ffmpeg, and can be used without additional codec installation. 
You can also find some examples there.

Comment: The codecs are correctly installed, in fact when I press play everything work fine. Does QtAV project fix the issue of the preview lacking?

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but can someone be helpful. You can use `play()` and `pause()` together its showing first frame (use `setPosition()` if need not first) and paused video.

Comment: For me, if I play the video, it is playing normally.
But if I want to set the first frame with play() / pause(), sometimes I see the first frame and everything is OK, but sometimes I see the first frame and then it is replaced by a gray mess of pixels. I wonder why there is just no function 'setFirstFrame'. It looks like the video playing functionality of QT is very unstable.